# preg_match to get file with any characters between 123- and .txt?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to use a preg_match to get a file that matches a certain condition. For example, I want to find a file named "123-stack-overflow.txt". There can be any characters after the 123- and before the .txt.

How can this be modified so it will work?

```
preg_match("/^$ID-(.+).txt/" , $name, $file);
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Madbreaks, Hurry up and answer it so I can change it! LOL

Comment: @Cofey Have an upvote, 671 is a nicer number :)

Comment: What do you mean by "get a file"?

Comment: @Cofey : 676 is more nice :D +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regexp `^123-.+\.txt$`

```
^       # Match start of string
123-    # Match the literal string 123-
(.+)    # Match anything after (captured)
\.txt   # Match the literal string .txt 
$       # Match end of string
```

php:

```
$str="123-stack-overflow.txt";

preg_match('/^123-(.+)\.txt$/',$str,$match);
echo $match[0];
echo $match[1];

>>> 123-stack-overflow.txt
>>> stack-overflow
```

Comment: I think your `*` should be a `+`

Answer (score 2):

```
//^ beginning of line<br/>
//preg_quote($ID, '/') Properly escaped id, in case it has control characters <br/>
//\\- escaped dash<br/>
//(.+) captured file name w/out extension <br/>
//\.txt extension<br/>
//$ end of line

    preg_match("/^".preg_quote($ID, '/')."\\-(.+)\\.txt$/" , $name, $file);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape . charchter

```
preg_match("/^$ID-(.+).txt/" , $name, $file);
```

should be

```
preg_match("/^$ID-(.+)\.txt^/U" , $name, $file);
```

if you want to match every number istead of $ID you can use

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]+-(.+)\.txt^/U" , $name, $file);
```